# (5.4-beta-6) How to update a Zone inside a loop?

Tags: tapestry

I have a loop that displays numerous components including a **Zone**. All all these components are inside a **Form** component.

Each iteration of this loop, shows a Select component that shows a **Zone** when the **Select** component's value is changed (i.e. **VALUE_CHANGED** event is triggered and the zone is updated).

When this loop has more than one iteration, for instance 2, I have 2 Select components but whether the first or second iteration's **Select** component's value is changed, only one **Zone** is updated, which was shown in the first iteration.

Let me rephrase if I wasn't clear. Assume you have a loop that displays a **Select** and a **Zone** component. Each loop displays what I'll call, a page section. How can each **Select** component update the **Zone** in the same section using Ajax ? (The trick is about knowing the zone's ID to be able to update it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<t:loop source="objects" value="object">
  <t:select t:id="select" model="model" value="value" zone="${zoneId}"></t:select>
  <t:zone t:id="zone" id="${zoneId}"></t:zone>
</t:loop>


@InjectComponent
private Zone zone;

public String getZoneId() {
   return "zone_" + object.getId(); // unique identifier
}

public void onValueChangedFromSelect() {
   ajaxresponseRenderer.addRender(zone); // now the correct zone will be updated
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.util.UnknownValueException: Could not find a coercion from type java.lang.String to type org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Zone.`. Does this method still work?